# Sharing value from custom middleware to anywhere

Tags: asp.net-core, session-cookies, middleware

I'm trying to pass the client IP address from the middleware to anywhere in the project.

I have made three attempts (session, cookie, items), but none of them is working.

I get the value using custom middleware as follows:

```
    public Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        var httpConnectionFeature = httpContext.Features.Get<IHttpConnectionFeature>();
        var remoteIpAddress = httpConnectionFeature?.RemoteIpAddress;
        //var remoteIpAddress = httpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress;

        if (remoteIpAddress.ToString() != "::1")
        {
            var cookieOptions = new CookieOptions
            {
                Secure = true,
                HttpOnly = true,
                SameSite = SameSiteMode.None,
                Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5),
                IsEssential = true
            };

            httpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("anonymousIP", remoteIpAddress.ToString(), cookieOptions);
            httpContext.Session.SetString("anonymousIP", remoteIpAddress.ToString());
            httpContext.Items.Add("anonymousIP", remoteIpAddress.ToString());
        }

        return _next(httpContext);
    }
```

but I can't receive it!

```
        var ctxt = Context.GetHttpContext();
        var x = ctxt.Session.GetString("anonymousIP");
        var y = ctxt.Items["anonymousIP"];
        var z = ctxt.Request.Cookies["anonymousIP"];
```

is there anything wrong? is it possible to share a value from the middleware to anywhere?

Comment: Hi @MedoofromEgypt, you use `Context.GetHttpContext()`, it seems you use signalr in your project. I test it with signalr in my asp.net core project and works fine. How do you design signalr? What is your Startup.cs like? Also, please debug your code and check if your `remoteIpAddress` contains value or not. Besides, the correct way to get cookie should be: `HttpContext.Response.GetTypedHeaders().SetCookie.First(a=>a.Name== "anonymousIP").Value.ToString();`.

Comment: yeah that's correct @Rena. I'm sing signalR. it seems situation htere is deffirent because I have tried many ways using DI, static classes, and custom middleware and none of them working. however, debugging the custom middleware gits the required value successfully. but I couldn't even pass it to my hub constructor. Ill updated the question very soon to add the whole code.

Answer (score 1):

for a similar requirement, I created a class as below

```
public class CurrentUserService : ICurrentUserService
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    public CurrentUserService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }
    public string MyVariable
    {
        get
        { 
            // get data as you need, e.g. from header or request object.
            return _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers["MyVariable"].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

then using Dependency Injection - inject "ICurrentUserService" anywhere you need.

Comment: thank you so much @Walnut. I tried your answer. however, I didn't find a reference to `ICurrentUserService`. I tried to make injection without interface just using `CurrentUserService` but I didn't get a value. I'll add the full code very soon to show my attempts.

Comment: @MedoofromEgypt ICurrentUserService is custom created interface, you can create from the class above. Also, check this repo - https://github.com/kberawala/ExampleApps